# PowerShell not targeting 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to run a PowerShell script inside C# using .NET 4.6 
I have tried to install the PowerShell NuGet but it doesn´t target .NET 4.6
Is there another way I could execute the PowerShell script?

I needed to specify powershell.exe to be able to run the script. But now I have another problem the PowerShell window closes immediately so I am not able to see the error message. I am using the following command

```
var s = Process.Start(@"Powershell.exe", $@"-noexit  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file ""MyScript.ps1; MyFunction"" ""{arguments}""");
s.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Can you add some of the code you're using?

Comment: Hi @DanSchnau see the updated code...

Comment: @doorman Powershell does work in .NET 4.6. What did you try and what was the problem? If what you said was true *nobody* would be able to use it - 4.6 is a binary replacement for all previous 4.x versions.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos basically I tried adding the Powershell Nuget package but it won´t install. Complains that it´s not targeted for 4.6

Comment: @doorman what NuGet package? System.Management.Automation.dll is installed locally, eg in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0`. There may be multiple instances if you have different versions installed on the same machine

Comment: This one... https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShell/1.0.0

Comment: @doorman if you refer to https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/ the description clearly says this is an *unofficial* version which hasn't been updated since 2013. Add the library directly

Comment: @doorman did you check the author of this package? Are you *sure* you didn't just install a Trojan on your machine? That package has nothing to do with Powershell or Microsoft

Comment: No I didn´t check that, I assumed this was the main powershell package.

Comment: @doorman the author is some random guy, the package has *no* downloads to speak of - even the unofficial package from 2013 has 400K downloads. Why don't you try one of the dozens of tutorials on Powershell, eg [Executing Powershell Scripts from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) or [Windows Powershell Host QuickStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn569260(v=vs.85).aspx) from MSDN?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a better look..

Comment: So I ended up using the automation library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192219/calling-powershell-ps1-file-using-system-management-automation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run it as you run any external program. `System.Diagnostics.Process` will help you out.

Here is a code example from [Microsoft community](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9218f9f0-8e9c-436a-892e-9cc7fa20310e/how-to-run-an-external-exe-program-and-pass-line-command-arguments-to-it-from-a-visual-studio-c?forum=csharpgeneral):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   Process myProcess = new Process();

   myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"ConsoleApplication1.exe";
   myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

   myProcess.Start();

   string redirectedOutput=string.Empty;
   while ((redirectedOutput += (char)myProcess.StandardOutput.Read()) != "Enter File Name:") ;

   myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("passedFileName.txt");

   myProcess.WaitForExit();

   //verifying that the job was successfull or not?!
   Process.Start("explorer.exe", "passedFileName.txt");
  }
 }
}
```

`ConsoleApplication1.exe` should be replaced with `YourApplication.ps1`

Why would you ever use `System.Diagnostics.Process` rather than `System.Management.Automation` which is recommended? Because powershell is slow and if you ever need to replace it, using `System.Diagnostics.Process` will allow doing it immediately.

Comment: Hi Mindaugas, thanks for your help. I updated my question, do you know how I can prevent the powershell window from closing, or how I can get the error that occurs in the script?

Comment: If the problem is in Powershell code, run the script on it's own w/o the calling code. To see the output / error message just call it from Powershell shell. Run > poershell > navigate the the scipt dir > run that Powershell script. It will print out the error.

Comment: Hi Mindaugas, when I call it from the powershell like this  powershell -executionPolicy bypass -noexit -file "myproject.ps1 myfunction" it complains that the file does not have a .ps1 extension. Is this the right way to trigger a function in a ps file?

Comment: There's no reason to use Process.Start at all because you *can* create a Powershell Pipeline in .NET.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos could you give an example using .NET 4.6?

Comment: @doorman every single one of them. What did you try and what was the problem? Did you add the System.Management.Automation dll?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so far I only tried using Process

Comment: Go w/ the .NET Powershell native approach only if you will stick to powershell. It is often that opwershell is only the initial approach and then when you rewrite it into something else you might need to rewrite the C# interface to your PS scripts as well.