# Calling Powershell ps1 file using System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following c# code:

```
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

var runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

// create a pipeline and feed it the script text
var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
var command = new Command(@". .\MyScript.ps1");
command.Parameters.Add("MyParam1", value1);
command.Parameters.Add("MyParam2", value2);
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

But I am getting the error Powershell ps1 file “is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file.”

MyScript.ps1 is copied to the bin folder so it is at the same level as the running program.

I found this [Powershell ps1 file "is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762927/powershell-ps1-file-is-not-recognized-as-a-cmdlet-function-operable-program)

But it did not solve the problem. Any idea what else could cause this error?

Comment: What is the output if you invoke `new Command("Get-Location");` instead?

Comment: Hi Mathias I will check later tonight. But I already tried reading the file to a variable and passing it in like this but I got the same error. I will let you know once I tried getlocation.

Comment: You should not use `.` before script file name.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is likely that your application inherits its working directory from the parent process, so you can't predict that `.` refers to the directory in which the executable resides.

You could construct the full path to the script with something like:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

// ...

string exePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);

string scriptPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder,"MyScript.ps1");

var command = new Command(". " + scriptPath);
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, I used your code but I still get the exception {"The term '. C:\\ProjectFolder\\bin\\Debug\\MyScript.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."} The path is correct and I can open the file. Any other idea why this could occur?

Comment: @doorman I had the same kind of problem but it was because we didn't escape the string for the other script properly. _i.e. you need_ `new Command(". '" + scriptPath + "'");`